# Xamarin INTERNET permission

Tags: android, http, xamarin, android-manifest

I am developing android app using Xamarin. I am using HttpWebRequest of C# for http conmunication in shared project.

It works without adding in android manifest, INTERNET permission.

Do I need to add permission in manifest?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not include the permissions , debug works fine but release will fail.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Android. If you are planning to support older devices (like <=3.0) you have to add it.

Comment: With Xamarin, and C#style http communication? I am supporting from 4.0 , will that effect play store permissions for user to install app?

Comment: If you want to be sure you should add the permission. You can never know for sure that it won't cause any problem if you miss the INTERNET permission.